# vim latex suite opens NO NAME buffer on cite completetion

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite

I'm using vim with latex-suite to edit my documents.
Each time I press F9 to complete a "\cite{", the outline opens, I can choose the correct reference and validate. Then the outline closes, but i have a buffer, that looks like "29:--NO NAME--1419627912" that remains open. Each time I complete, another one opens, and it quickly grows out of control...

It seems no one has this problem, thouh i have it on all my documents, and all computers (2 fedoras 20 and a centos 5)

Does anyone have an idea why ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I don't know if there's a conflict, or what's causing the bug.

But I found the solution here: http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/28747891/

As it says, make the following changes in `ftplugin/latex-suite/texviewer.vim`

```
@@ -855,7 +856,8 @@ function! Tex_FindBibFiles()
         call Tex_Debug(":Tex_FindBibFiles: ", "view")

         let mainfname = Tex_GetMainFileName(':p')
-       exec 'new ' . fnameescape(mainfname)
+       split
+       exec 'silent! e '.fnameescape(mainfname)

         if search('\\\(no\)\?bibliography{', 'w')
```